# "Z," "Tab," "1," and "ESC" keys are acting weird

Tags: shortcut-keys

If I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, it opens a window to shutdown, log off, etc. the computer. The <kbd>Z</kbd> key does "undo". The number one key reloads the page. The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key acts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. If I try to use any of the keys, it won't work unless I press it quickly multiple times. I don't have any sticky keys enabled under System → Preferences → Assistive Technologies.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the version of Ubuntu you're using and the make/model of your computer?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is stuck (<kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> is normally undo). Try a different keyboard (if on a laptop, try an external one) to see if that works.

Also try cleaning your keyboard.

Comment: Thank you. I just plugged in my USB keyboard, and it worked, is there a way to get the key "unstuck?"

Comment: The only way to get it unstuck is to clean it. SUCCESS!!!